# Wpf Combobox DataBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

hello everyone it is me again! i've got few problems too.  i am deveoping an training software that's why i am asking lots of questions.i hope you help me. thanks in advance. 
my problems are as follows:

**First of all:** i have a register window that has a combobox. i have binded it an access datasource. the problem is when i select an item, it doesnt select. it writes System.data.Datarow.(i want it list names like mike,susan ect.)

**how can i fix it?**  where is the problem?

```
public Register()
{                   
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Select();

}

public void Select()
{

    DataView view;
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
    con.Open();
    string sql = "Select * from UserInformation";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "UserInformation");
    view = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    RegCombo.ItemsSource = view;

    con.Close();
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    Margin="0,22.447,46.92,0" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=UserName}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" 
    IsEditable="True" IsDropDownOpen="False" MaxDropDownHeight="266.666666666667" 
    FontSize="16" x:Name="RegCombo" FontWeight="Normal"  >

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserName}"></TextBlock>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Your Binding source is a DataView.  DataView doesn't have a UserName property, and I don't think WPF binding special-cases column names.  I could be wrong about this, though: if you look at the Output window while running in the debugger, you'll probably see some binding error messages which give you some more idea of why the binding is failing.

Comment: This page use DataReader, but it might give you some idea. Cheers. [http://itbethyname.com/2011/how-to-databind-a-combobox-in-wpf-using-c-or-vb-net/](http://itbethyname.com/2011/how-to-databind-a-combobox-in-wpf-using-c-or-vb-net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) on your ComboBox to be the property on the underlying object you want to see in the `ItemsControl`

If this is not specified, and you have not overridden the `ToString()` method on that object, you will just see (what you are now seeing) - the qualified name of the object.

Comment: Suggest clarifying that if he sets DMP he does not need the ItemTemplate any more (in fact I think ItemTemplate overrides DMP and would therefore have to be removed for DMP to work).

Comment: thanks LanR, i did what you said. i solved the problems. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=UserName}"

Comment: That will look for a UserName property on the TextBlock itself.  RelativeSource Self refers to the FrameworkElement on whose property the Binding is being set.